# Kendo UI Gantt refresh after update

Tags: kendo-ui, refresh, kendo-gantt

I have a gantt chart which when I move or change the date start/end, updates the database but doesn't persist on the gantt. I have to reload the gantt to see the change. Is there a way of extending the update event to refresh after update?

```
$("#gantt_here").kendoGantt({
                            dataSource: {
                                batch: true,
                                transport: {
                                    read: {
                                        url: "http://URL/gantt/<?= $client ?>/<?= $project ?>",
                                        dataType: "json"
                                    },
                                    update: {
                                        url: "http://URL/ganttUpdate/<?= $client ?>/<?= $project ?>",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        method: "post"
                                    },
                                    create: {
                                        url: "http://URL/<?= $client ?>/<?= $project ?>",
                                        dataType: "json"
                                    },
                                    destroy: {
                                        url: "http://URL/ganttDestroy/<?= $client ?>/<?= $project ?>",
                                        dataType: "json"
                                    },
                                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                        if (operation !== "read") {
                                            return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models || [options])};
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                schema: {
                                    model: {
                                        id: "id",
                                        fields: {
                                            id: {from: "id", type: "number"}, //
                                            orderId: {from: "orderId", type: "number", validation: {required: true}}, //
                                            parentId: {from: "parent", type: "number", validation: {required: true}}, //
                                            start: {from: "start", type: "date"}, //
                                            end: {from: "end", type: "date"}, //
                                            title: {from: "title", defaultValue: "", type: "string"}, //
                                            percentComplete: {from: "percentComplete", type: "number"}, //
                                            client: {from: "client", type: "number", validation: {required: true}}, //
                                            project: {from: "project", type: "string", validation: {required: true}}, //
                                            summary: true,
                                            expanded: true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was experiencing (and I can't find it mentioned anywhere on the KendoUI website docs!) is that you need to return the updated data row once you update. Returning this initiates the refresh of that particular row and retains the move/update

The only thing I changed other than that was to change the transport method from JSON to JSONP on read and update.